# Method has automatic access to build context

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is a method that is called within my application when a 'save' button is pressed. The method accesses a `ChangeNotifier` instance using the `Provider` object and updates the underlying model.

```dart
  /// Handle the user pressing the Submit button within the dialog.
  void _saveChanges() {
    // HANDLING DEGREE OBJECT //

    // degree title
    Provider.of<AcademicController>(context, listen: false)
        .setDegreeTitle(titleController.text);

    // degree award
    Provider.of<AcademicController>(context, listen: false)
        .setDegreeAward(awardController.text);

    // HANDLING ACADEMIC YEAR OBJECTS //

    // removing academic years to be removed
    Provider.of<AcademicController>(context, listen: false)
        .removeListOfAcademicYears(academicYearsToBeRemoved);

    // saving the changes made within to the academic year form rows
    for (AcademicYearFormRow academicYearFormRow in academicYearFormRows) {
      academicYearFormRow.saveChanges(context);
    }
  }
```

I am confused because, in this method, I reference `context`, but I do not pass in a `BuildContext` as an argument to the function.

The method is not nested and occurs at the same level as the widget's build method.

How does this method have access to a `BuildContext` without getting one as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `_saveChanges` method is a member of a `StatefulWidget`'s `State`, the `context` is most likely the [`State.context`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/context.html). The `context` passed to the [`State.build`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html) method is always the `State.context` and does not change over the lifetime of a `State`. According to the documentation of `State.build`

> The [BuildContext](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html) argument is provided redundantly here so that this method matches the signature for a [WidgetBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetBuilder.html).

Comment: Thanks - that will be it. I did not know that was the behaviour of the `StatefulWidget`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether that method is inside a `StatelessWidget` or a `StatefulWidget`. I find that for a `StatefulWidget`, the `context` is available globally within the class without needing to pass an instance of `BuildContext` to any method.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense and seems to be the case!